# Вывести заданное число файлов из расположенных в директории

Tags: linux, консоль, rhel

Какой командой в консоли можно вывести заданное число файлов из расположенных в директории?

Comment: проведите, пожалуйста, декомпозицию вашего комплексного вопроса, и задайте по отдельности каждый из этих вопросов. их как минимум три.

Comment: Вроде поправил.

Comment: уже сократили до двух под-вопросов. так держать!

Comment: Исправил. Так уже получше?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

программа *ls* возвращает некоторое количество строк, по строке для каждого файла, либо напрямую указанного аргументом(-ами), либо присутствующего в каталоге(-ах) переданного(-ых) программе в качестве аргумента(-ов).

для того, чтобы оставить лишь часть из них, можно воспользоваться программами *head* и *tail*.

оставить первые (например) пять строк:

```
$ ls каталог | head -n 5
```

оставить последние (например) десять строк:

```
$ ls каталог | tail -n 10
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, очень помогли!